# Dice Game in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to spew out randomly generated dice for every roll that the user plays. The user has 3 rolls per turn and he gets to play 5 turns (I haven't implemented this part yet and I would appreciate suggestions).

I'm also wondering how I can display the colors randomly. I have the list of tuples in place, but I reckon I need some function that uses random and that list to match those colors. I'm struggling as to how.

```
module Main where

import System.IO
import System.Random
import Data.List

diceColor = [("Black",1),("Green",2),("Purple",3),("Red",4),("White",5),("Yellow",6)]

{-
randomList :: (RandomGen g) -> Int -> g -> [Integer]
random 0 _ = []
randomList n generator = r : randomList (n-1) newGenerator
        where (r, newGenerator) = randomR (1, 6) generator
-}

rand :: Int -> [Int] -> IO ()
rand n rlst = do
    num <- randomRIO (1::Int, 6)
    if n == 0
        then doSomething rlst
        else rand (n-1) (num:rlst)

doSomething x = putStrLn (show (sort x))

main :: IO ()
main = do
    --hSetBuffering stdin LineBuffering
    putStrLn "roll, keep, score?"
    cmd <- getLine
    doYahtzee cmd
    --rand (read cmd) []

doYahtzee :: String -> IO ()
doYahtzee cmd = do
if cmd == "roll" 
    then rand 5 []
        else do print "You won"
```

Comment: You cannot have the code that implements a function flush left with the name of the function. In other words, you need to indent every line after your `do` statement inside a function.

Comment: I did indent it, it's not showing properly above. Anyhow, I got over the indentation problem for the main (although I still have it for the list of tuples), I now get : "Exception: Prelude.read: no parse" error when I type "roll".

Comment: For maximum help, be sure to post the code you actually use, indentation included.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's really a lot of errors sprinkled throughout this code, which suggests to me that you tried to build the whole thing at once. This is a recipe for disaster; you should be building very small things and testing them often in ghci.

Lecture aside, you might find the following facts interesting (in order of the associated errors in your code):

- `List` is deprecated; you should use `Data.List` instead.
- No `let` is needed for top-level definitions.
- Variable names must begin with a lower case letter.
- Class prerequisites are separated from a type by `=>`.
- The top-level module block should mainly have definitions; you should associate every `where` clause (especially the one near `randomList`) with a definition by either indenting it enough not to be a new line in the module block or keeping it on the same line as the definition you want it to be associated with.
- `do` introduces a block; those things in the block should be indented equally and more than their context.
- `doYahtzee` is declared and used as if it has three arguments, but seems to be defined as if it only has one.
- The `read` function is used to parse a `String`. Unless you know what it does, using `read` to parse a `String` from another `String` is probably not what you want to do -- especially on user input.
- `putStrLn` only takes one argument, not four, and that argument has to be a `String`. However, making a guess at what you wanted here, you might like the `(!!)` and `print` functions.
- `dieRoll` doesn't seem to be defined anywhere.

It's possible that there are other errors, as well. Stylistically, I recommend that you check out `replicateM`, `randomRs`, and `forever`. You can use [hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) to search for their names and read more about them; in the future, you can also use it to search for functions you wish existed by their type.

Comment: Thanks for the input Daniel. I've fixed the code and it compiles! (I've edited my post) I still would like to know how to print colors instead of numbers.

Comment: @rexbelia Please revert this question to the old problem, and open a new question with the new problem. Stack Overflow is intended to be a long-term archive of questions and answers, and as such it is bad style to change a question so much that it invalidates all the answers.